# iterate over repository and get file modified time

Tags: java

I did it like this

```
Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (!attrs.isDirectory()) {
            LocalDateTime timestamp =
                LocalDateTime.ofInstant(attrs.lastModifiedTime().toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        ...
```

In `Java 8` I can use `Files.walk`

```
        Files.walk(Paths.get(EXTENSION_FOLDER))
                ... // some stream method
```

But how to get `modifiedTime` in that case? Neither `Path` nor `File` provide that ability.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html: *Usage Example:

    Path file = ...
    BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called `lastModified`.

JavaDoc: [File.lastModified#](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified())